# Toshiba estudio 385s Ubuntu supported?

Tags: 14.04, printing, toshiba

We have a new device at the office. A Toshiba estudio 385s, which also has a scanner.

Their webpresence is rather bad. Are there any drivers for Ubuntu?:
http://www.toshibatec.ch/de/mod/Produkte/SchwarzWeissgerate/e-STUDIO385S

Answer (score 1):

Have successfully used our Toshiba estudio 280 copier(different model from yours) as a printer.   Ubuntu 14.10 recognized and autoconfigured easily via ethernet. In System Settings, chose Printer then Ubuntu took care of the rest.